# How to integrate Redux DevTools with ReactOnRails

Tags: redux, react-on-rails

I'd like to integrate Redux DevTools (https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) with ReactOnRails (https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) project.

I'm not sure where I can put

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

as I created the store from the action in Rails itself. E.g:

```
redux_store('myStore', props: store_json_string)
```

So, where should I put the configuration for Redux in my Rails app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you've run `react_on_rails` with `--redux` flag, you can configure it by adding the desired line inside the `/app/javascript/bundles/HelloWorld/store/helloWorldStore.js` file in `createStore`:

```
  // ...
  createStore(
    helloWorldReducer,
    railsProps,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
  // ...
```